# Area between two curves when $x=f(y)$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have these two curves: $x=e^y$ and $x=y^2-2$. I want to find the area between them then the area is bounded by $y=±1$. The picture explains it better than I can.[image]

I was wondering what the best way to go about it is? I was thinking to rearrange for x and find the new bounds in terms of x? Of just integrate in terms of y like this:

$$\int_{-1}^1 y^2-2 \,dy - \int_{-1}^1 e^y \,dy $$

Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: Right curve minus left curve

Comment: Ahhhh thank you :)

Comment: No, it is not because you have it backwards!  The curve $x= e^y$ is to the right of $x= y^2- 2$ because, for all y between -1 and 1, $e^y> y^2- 2$.  Doing it your way you would get a **negative** area.  Instead the area is equal to $\int_{-1}^1 e^y- y^2+ 2 dy$

Comment: @Jamesodare Used your pic in my answer. Hope OK.

Comment: @Narasimham No problem, thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not switch back (to the original functions) from which all this is made? That is by using inverse functions where $(x,y)$ are swapped?

[image: Inv Fns]

Then you simply need to evaluate direct

$$ \int_{-1}^1 (e^{x} -(x^2-2) ) dx $$

Answer (score 2):

Answer:

$$ -\int_{-1}^1 y^2-2 \,dy + \int_{-1}^1 e^y \,dy= e- \frac{1}{e} +\frac{10}{3}$$

Answer (score 0):

The rule is simple: the area bounded by two curves is top curve minus bottom curve. Turn your head 90 degrees to the right and you will see that $x=e^y$ is the curve that lies above the curve $x=y^2-2$:

$$\int_{-1}^{1}[e^y-(y^2-2)]\,dy=\int_{-1}^{1}(e^y-y^2+2)\,dy.$$